# How to post the value of the variable in the API end point link?

Tags: node.js, api

The value Sydney is assigned to the variable city and now how do i post the value of the variable in the below api end point and receive the appropriate json

If I post the value "Sydney" directly in the end point , then the json returns

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=madurai&units=metric&appid={API_KEY}

But if i post as ${city} , then the value "Sydney" doesn't get posted , I should be able to post the value of the variable

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid={API_KEY}

```
let city = "Sydney" ;  //here this value must be posted in the below link
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid={API_KEY}
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
if(err)
{
  console.log(err);
} 
else 
{
  let weather = JSON.parse(body)
  if(weather.main == undefined)
  {
   console.log("undefined");
  } 
  else 
  {
   console.log(weather);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to use a template literal: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Don't you just need to do:

```
const city = "Sydney"
const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=9ae40b8fdec0b4d7bc95aa14b4393ce3`
```

Notice the type of quotes around the url string.

Comment: @Godwin , If this answer is correct, please accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Please try mentioned code:

```
var request   = require("request");
let city = "Sydney" ;  //here this value must be posted in the below link
let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=9ae40b8fdec0b4d7bc95aa14b4393ce3"
console.log(url);
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else  {
    let weather = JSON.parse(body)
    if(weather.main == "undefined") {
      console.log("undefined");
    } else {
      console.log(weather);
    }
  }
});
```